# Is there a timezone name for tzID GMT-8

Tags: ios

- One of our user lives in US and he travelled to India.
- His device timeZone was set to America/Los_Angeles
- With code below, `self.tzID` is set to `PST`

  ```
  NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
  self.tzID = [timeZone abbreviation];
  ```
- I can then correctly get the TZName as `America/Los_Angeles` with code:

  ```
  NSDictionary *tzDict = [NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary];
  NSString *tzName = [tzDict objectForKey:self.tzID];
  ```

The problem is when he is India, `tzID` is set to **GMT-8** and `tzDict` does not have any key **GMT-8** which makes `tzName` `nil`.

- Is there a timezone name for tzID **GMT-8**
- If so, how can I get tzName for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be wary about using abbreviations to look up names in the dictionary. The problem is that abbreviations are ambiguous (the same abbreviation has different meanings in different places). Worse, you can't just look up what `NSTimeZone` is GMT-8, because there are currently seven of them, so you have no way of knowing which the user intended.

So, you really shouldn't use abbreviations for the purposes of lookups. Use `timeZone.name` (or, in Swift 3, `timeZone.identifier`) not `abbreviation`.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get the name of a time zone is by asking for its localized name. For example:

```
NSString *name = [timeZone localizedName:NSTimeZoneNameStyleGeneric locale:nil];
```

This will return a correctly localized name for the time zone. Depending on what you need, you can use different styles, including "standard" and "short standard," "daylight saving," etc.

If you need to distinguish between standard and DST, use `isDaylightSavingTimeForDate:` to determine which to use.